# Failed to run facebook login due to error Calling to a member function getLoginUrl()

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, fatal-error

I unsure on how to code for session calling the FB if there any. However, I've added this at all pages which I want my facebook to be loaded. I believe it is the Facebook SDK. For example, I add this code in my register.php and login.php.

```
<body>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo $config['appId']; ?>',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I also added this in my config.php which I believe it is Config for FB Login.

```
$config = array();
```

However, everytime I tried to click on the Facebook button in my login.php, there will be error such that

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object
>   in C:\wamp\www\sggrocer\loginFb.php on line 13

**loginFB.php**

```
<?php   
    session_start();
    include('ajax-helper/config.php');

    $_SESSION[$PROJECT_NAME . '-loginFb'] = true;
    unset($_SESSION[$PROJECT_NAME . '-logout']);

    $params = array(
      'scope' => 'email, user_birthday',
      'redirect_uri' => $base_url . "http://localhost/sggrocer/",
    );

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

    header('Location:' . $loginUrl);

?>
```

This is my login.php: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Snurainiyakob/V4u5X/872/

And the UI as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu6Rl.jpg)

At which page should i initialise $facebook object? I follow through what is available online, but i don't seem to get it right.

Comment: Where is `$facebook` supposed to come from in your script?

Comment: Based on my code, i've added $facebook in my loginFB.php. Did i missed out any codes? Because it keep giving me the same error which I don't know what it is.

Comment: _“i've added $facebook in my loginFB.php”_ – and what exactly did you add, what type of object _is_ `$facebook` now actually? I suggest you have a look at the basic login example in the SDK documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0